# PowerShell Importing CSV

Tags: powershell

I'm importing a CSV. I have a column called 'Date of Birth' with dates formatted as 'yyyy/MM/dd' and 'yyyy-MM-dd'.

I'm only looking to pull records where the date is in the latter format (yyyy-MM-dd)

My code below works, but it's not pulling any records back for $SearchFor = "-" and when using 
$SearchFor = "/" I'm being returned all records.

```
Import-CSV C:\Test\TestFile.csv | Where-Object { $_."Date Of Birth" -Notlike $SearchFor } | ForEach-Object {
```

Does anyone know what's going on, and how I can only get the records I'm looking for?

Comment: You can use `-match` for this --> `Where-Object { $_."Date Of Birth" -match '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}' }`

Comment: Why does the format of the date matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be getting back all records regardless if your query is:

```
$_."Date Of Birth" -Notlike $SearchFor
```

Where `$SearchFor` is either `"-"` or `"/"`

You need to add wildcards and use `"*-*"` and `"*/*"` otherwise the `-like` operator behaves similar to the `-eq` operator.

Better yet, use regex to match the exact formats which seem to be set in stone:

Match dates with dashes: `$SearchFor = "^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$"`

```
$_."Date Of Birth" -match $SearchFor
```

To match dates with slashes, just slightly edit the regex query string: `$SearchFor = "^\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}$"`